The multiplicative group of units in the Clifford algebra is open

For any finite-dimensional real or complex vector space $V$ and symmetric bilinear form $g$ on $V$, the Clifford algebra Cl($V,g$) has a natural smooth structure, arising from its vector space structure. The multiplicative group of units is defined to be
$$
\mathrm{Cl}(V, g)^\times:=\{\varphi\in \mathrm{Cl}(V, g)| \exists \varphi^{-1}\ \mathrm{s.t. }\ \varphi\varphi^{-1}=\varphi^{-1}\varphi=1\}.
$$

I want to prove that Cl($V,g$)$^\times$ is an open manifold, and thus a Lie subgroup. I have known

The dimension of the clifford algebra is $2^\mathrm{dim}V$
$V-\{0\}\subset Cl(V,g)^\times$

Appreciate any help or hint!

This is not specific to Clifford algebras and is true for any finite-dimensional real or complex algebra $A$. To prove it you can pick any faithful linear representation $A \to M_n(\mathbb{C})$ (for example the regular representation, coming from $A$ acting on itself) and consider the determinant.

I now know Cl$(V, g)^\times \to$ GL(Cl$(V,g)$) is injective by considering the representation Cl$(V, g)^\times\times$ Cl$(V,g)\to $Cl$(V,g) $, so what should I do next? Your comment can be more helpful to me if you are willing to add more details.

It's not necessary to use any specific facts about Clifford algebras here. Here is a general argument. Let $A$ be a finite-dimensional algebra over $K = \mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$. $A$ admits some faithful matrix representation $\rho : A \to M_n(K)$, for example the regular representation given by $A$ acting by left multiplication on itself. Since this representation is faithful, it follows that $a \in A$ is invertible iff $\rho(a) \in M_n(K)$ is invertible, and furthermore $\rho(a)$ is invertible iff $\det \rho(a) \in K$ is nonzero.
So the group $GL(A)$ of units of $A$ is given by the preimage of the open set $K^{\times} = K \setminus \{ 0 \}$ under the (polynomial, hence) continuous (with respect to the Euclidean topologies) map $\det \rho$, which means that $GL(A)$ is open as desired. In the real case this means $GL(A)$ is a Lie group and in the complex case this means that $GL(A)$ is a complex Lie group. Over an arbitrary field it is an algebraic group.

In any unital Banach algebra $A$, the units form an open subset. This is not a hard fact.
If $a\in A$ is invertible, then for any $b\in A$, we have $a-b=a(1-a^{-1}b)$, and for sufficiently small $b$ (indeed whenenver $\|b\|<\|a^{-1}\|^{-1}$), $\|a^{-1}b\|<1$, then the Neumann series converges: $$(1-a^{-1}b)^{-1}=\sum_{i=0}^\infty (a^{-1}b)^i$$
Now we can equip a finite dimensional (unital) real/complex algebra with any submultiplicative norm (which must induce the unique topology that makes it a real/complex topological vector space), to apply the above argument. For example, we can pick an arbitrary vector space norm $\|\cdot\|$ on $A$, then equip $A$ with the operator norm $\|a\|_{op}=\max_{\|x\|\le 1}\|ax\|$.
